# Simpler way to call a function in a same table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I wonder if there's a simpler way to call a function or set variable of the same table instead of writing the table name.

For example, Is there a simpler way to call `MyClass.test()` function from `MyClass.setup()` in my below example code?

```
local MyClass = {}

function MyClass.test()
  print("Hello")
end

function MyClass.setup()
  MyClass.test()
end

MyClass.setup()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `:` to call the functions instead of `.`, Lua implicitly inserts a reference to the table itself as the first argument (similar to the `this` pointer is some object-oriented languages).  Then you can say `self:test()` to get rid of the name dependence.

```
local MyClass = {
    test = function(self)
        print("Hello")
    end,
    setup = function(self)
        self:test()
    end
}

MyClass:setup()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is this a common style to directly write functions inside a table `{ }` for OOP-like design in Lua?

Comment: I don't know.  For such short function I tend to put them inline.  Otherwise you can define them outside the table with `function MyClass:setup() self:test() end`, see this [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7kTssTAy8bvdGpDf).

Answer (score 2):

You can set the module table to be the environment:

```
local print = print
local _ENV = {}

function test()
  print("Hello")
end

function setup()
  test()
end

setup()

return _ENV
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local MyClass = {}
function MyClass:Setup()
    print('hello...Setup')
end

function MyClass:Test()
    self:Setup() -- self -> MyClass
    print('hello...Test')
end

MyClass:Test()
-- or inherit
local newClass = MyClass
newClass:Test()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
local MyClass = {}

function MyClass.test()
  print("Hello")
end

function MyClass.setup(self)
  self.test()
end

MyClass.setup(MyClass)
```

the key is `self`. In the state, `MyClass` is a obj and create by `{}`, so you can use `MyClass.Test(MyClass)` to incoming parameters `MyClass` to use the `func test()` of `MyClass` obj.

**ps**:
Syntax sugar provided by Lua：
MyClass.setup(MyClass) ==>  MyClass:setup()